# Unwind an array in DocumentDB query

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have documents that look like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "e1bb9b05-11f2-459e-37d3-9bf9fed56c96",
    "name": "bulbasaur",
    "type": [
      {
        "slot": 2,
        "type": {
          "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/",
          "name": "poison"
        }
      },
      {
        "slot": 1,
        "type": {
          "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/",
          "name": "grass"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The following query is about as close as I can get, but not quite the output I'm hoping for.

**Query**

```
SELECT
  c.id, c.name, t.type.name as type
FROM
  c
JOIN
  t IN c.types
WHERE
  c.name = "bulbasaur"
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "id": "e1bb9b05-11f2-459e-37d3-9bf9fed56c96",
    "name": "bulbasaur",
    "type": "poison"
  },
  {
    "id": "e1bb9b05-11f2-459e-37d3-9bf9fed56c96",
    "name": "bulbasaur",
    "type": "grass"
  }
]
```

**Hoping for**

```
[
  {
    "id": "e1bb9b05-11f2-459e-37d3-9bf9fed56c96",
    "name": "bulbasaur",
    "types": ["poison", "grass"]
  }
]
```

Is this possible with a DocumentDB query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires use of [DocumentDB UDFs](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/documentdb-programming/#udf), which can extend query functionality with custom transformations. For example, register this:

```
  function unwindTypeArray(value) {
    var result = { id: value.id, name: value.name, types: []};
    for (var idx in value.type) {
      console.log(idx);
      var name = value.type[idx].type.name;
      result.types.push(name);
    }

    return result; 
}
```

Then call it inside a query like:

```
SELECT udf.unwindTypeArray(c) FROM c WHERE c.name = "bulbasaur"
```

Comment: Might want to add that you can create UDF's from the `Azure Portal > DocumentDB > Script explorer`